# How do I include youtube videos in a carousel on Google sites using embedded custom code?

Tags: html, youtube, google-sites

The html box embed feature on google sites is great. Google provides a good example of how to build a 3-slide carousel with text or logos for content. However, I'm struggling with how to add youtube videos to the content.

I've tried putting this in the content section:

```
iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ski_4N0dfFI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>/iframe
```

but google sites complains that the `src` tag is not allowed here. I suspect this is some sort of security restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Just try.

```
<object data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ski_4N0dfFI">
Cannot load video.
</object>
```

Or

```
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ski_4N0dfFI">
```